# Writing file paths into XML file with XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, file, xmlwriter

I'm hoping someone can help me with this annoying little problem I'm having. I'm trying to write a file path to an XML settings file, but nothing happens. I don't get any error messages or Just in Time debugging windows, it just doesn't execute that code block.

The program feature is one where you setup user accounts, and select a file for each account. If I leave the file paths blank, the XML file is created with no problems. However, if there is even one path to be written the file never even gets created.

Here is a sample of my function:

```
private void SaveSettings()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xml_settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xml_settings.Indent = true;
        xml_settings.IndentChars = ("    ");

        using (XmlWriter xml_settings_file = XmlWriter.Create("settings.xml", xml_settings))
        {
            xml_settings_file.WriteStartElement("Main_Node");
            xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("SettingA", Properties.Settings.Default.SettingA.ToString());
            xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("SettingB", Properties.Settings.Default.SettingB.ToString());
            xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("SettingC", Properties.Settings.Default.SettingC.ToString());

            for (int i = 1; i < Properties.Settings.Default.UserAccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("Account", System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(Properties.Settings.Default.UserAccounts[i].ToString()));
                xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("File", System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(Properties.Settings.Default.FilePaths[i]));
            }

            xml_settings_file.WriteEndElement();
            xml_settings_file.Flush();
        }

    }
```

To make things more confusing, when I replace the FilePath variable with a simple "Test" string, it works fine and the file is created with no problems.

Comment: you need to encode xml entities, not escape

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? Does it call your `SaveSettings` method? Does it get to the loop and then mysteriously quit? Does it run any code that might run after this point or does it terminate all processing there?

Comment: I don't see anything terribly wrong beside your `for` starting with 1 and double escaping of `File` and `Account` values. Are you sure `SaveSettings` is being ran at all? Can you walk through in the debugger and see where it stops?

Comment: I'm starting the loop at 1 because there is a dummy node at position 0 that I don't want to be written to the file.

Comment: Chris: I'm not 100% sure how to "step" through the code, but I placed a messagebox after the using statement and the message still pops up, but no file gets created. It doesn't even make the file with the first few settings.

Comment: vittore: The XmlSettings object defaults with UTF-8 encoding. Should it be something else?

Comment: "never gets created"? Exactly what happens?

Comment: John, it's strange. The "settings.xml" file doesn't get created at all if I put a file path in my variable. However, it does save the setting in the StringCollection in my application settings file. If I run the application again and immediately run my SaveSettings() method it writes the file just fine. I've never seen anything like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has yet to be solved. I ended up just using the built-in application settings instead.

Comment: Not really an answer... I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using CDATA instead of escaping path characters.

You can replace:

```
xml_settings_file.WriteElementString("File", System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(Properties.Settings.Default.FilePaths[i]));
```

with following lines:

```
xml_settings_file.WriteStartElement("File");
xml_settings_file.WriteCData(Properties.Settings.Default.FilePaths[i]);
xml_settings_file.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: This didn't do anything. Still getting the same result.